# unable to start container process: exec: "/opt/sentry/postgres-entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker

Following the sentry [self-hosted/#getting-started](https://develop.sentry.dev/self-hosted/#getting-started) documentation to install the sentry in WSL ubuntu 20.04

Got an error after executing the `./install.sh`.

```
 ...
 Container sentry-self-hosted-kafka-1  Healthy
 Container sentry-self-hosted-snuba-outcomes-consumer-1  Starting
 Container sentry-self-hosted-smtp-1  Started
 Container sentry-self-hosted-symbolicator-1  Started
 Container sentry-self-hosted-memcached-1  Started
 Container sentry-self-hosted-snuba-subscription-consumer-transactions-1  Started
 Container sentry-self-hosted-vroom-1  Started
 Container sentry-self-hosted-snuba-replacer-1  Started
 Container sentry-self-hosted-snuba-sessions-consumer-1  Started
 Container sentry-self-hosted-snuba-outcomes-consumer-1  Started
 Container sentry-self-hosted-snuba-consumer-1  Started
 Container sentry-self-hosted-snuba-subscription-consumer-events-1  Started
 Container sentry-self-hosted-snuba-api-1  Started
 Container sentry-self-hosted-snuba-transactions-consumer-1  Started
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/opt/sentry/postgres-entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown
Error in install/set-up-and-migrate-database.sh:12.
'$dcr web upgrade' exited with status 1
-> ./install.sh:main:34
--> install/set-up-and-migrate-database.sh:source:12

Cleaning up...
```

docker version:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.5
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.6
 Git commit:        ced0996
 Built:             Fri Jul 21 20:35:23 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.5
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.6
  Git commit:       a61e2b4
  Built:            Fri Jul 21 20:35:23 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.22
  GitCommit:        8165feabfdfe38c65b599c4993d227328c231fca
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.8
  GitCommit:        v1.1.8-0-g82f18fe
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```